# HighCharts.js TickInterval dynamic change

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I Have a system where I retrieve for Data.
I'm using Highcharts, Jquery on a HTML page for the Client Side of my app

Consider this,
Sometimes I can receive 10000 points, sometimes I can receive 10 points, so very random amount of data. Value are in Unix Milliseconds timestamp, but that's not a problem, I will process as I prefer.

What I don't understand it's: **How can I make a Dynamic TickInterval** useful both for many points, both for small amount of points?

```
xAxis: {
                tickInterval: ?? ,
                categories: [<%- nDate %>]               
            },
```

PS. No need for the code guys, only for a correct way of solve my problem, thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case when you have datatime type of xAxis, you don't need to use categories, you can set type as "datetime" and i.e use tickPositioner which allows to calculate ticks, dynamically.

See example: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: So if I understand according to example, in the X Axis I've to insert for example my unix timestamp values, below on `series: [{
            data: [] }]` I've to insert the couple [timestamp, values] ?

Comment: Ok i solved using tickpositioner on both axis, and the couple [timestamp,value] on Data field inside Series. Thanks